# Avoid impulse accumulation of an sprite when tapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm making my first iOS game using SpriteKit, and I'm applying an impulse for my sprite each time I tap on the screen, something like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    _ball.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
    [_ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 5)];
}
```

I'm trying to avoid the accumulation of impulses setting the sprite velocity to zero before applying the impulse but It seems not working. I also was thinking in conditionally impulse the sprite by doing it only when its velocity is zero, but it neither doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {

    CGVector vecVelocity = _ball.physicsBody.velocity;

    if(vecVelocity.dx == 0 && vecVelocity.sx == 0) {

        [_ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 5)];
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the answer. I'm currently working with the accelerometer, so I just needed to compare the `dy` component of the velocity. Thank you very much.